# The neural networks is compiled but the training does not start

Tags: python, command-line, centos, theano, keras

I wanted to train a neural network using keras, but the training does not start, and it happens in really weird situations.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(8, 7, 7, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(1, 31, 31), activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(16, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', activation='tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(23))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(11))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

optimizer = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
print("optimizer done")
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
print("compile done")
sys.stdout.flush()

model.fit(dataset, labels, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1, verbose=2)
```

If I run this code in the terminal using `python mynn.py`, everything goes fine and the training starts.

But if I run this code in the terminal using `python mynn.py &`, `python mynn.py > results.txt`, or if I redirect the outputs in my code `sys.stdout = open('Outputs.txt', 'w')`, then the program stall for the `fit` method, so the learning does not start. The `compile done`is displayed, but nothing more, no training.

I took a look and it seems that the program keeps calling this function `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, {,}) = 0`

Any ideas why it does not start when I redirect the outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the process starts but nothing is displayed into the terminal or written into the output file until the training is completely over (all the epoch performed).

I found out by starting many different small trainings with just few epochs, and everything was displayed only when all the trainings were over.